# adding date and numbers into same array

Tags: php, mysql, flot

im pulling data from a database which includes numbers with decimal places, and dates.

i am using the following code:

```
<?php
// Main query to pull data from 'tests' table
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `tests` WHERE member_id = '1'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die ("no query");

//  Dataset1
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $dataset1[] = array (intval($row['date']),intval($row['test1']));
    }
?>
```

this should output data when i echo for example:

date: 2011-09-15
test1: 1.024

but its actually only outputting the following:

date: 2011
test1: 1

i am then using this data to plot graphs using FLOT.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //Chart1
    var chart1Options = {
      series: {
        lines: { show: true },
        color: "#fff",
        points: { show: true }
      },
           valueLabels: {
                show: true
            },
    grid: {
          backgroundColor: { colors: ["#4ca8fa", "#2887da"] },
          hoverable: true //IMPORTANT! this is needed for tooltip to work
    }
    };
    var dataset1 = { label: "Salinity", data: <?php echo json_encode($dataset1); ?>,};

    $.plot($("#chart1"), [ dataset1 ], chart1Options);
</script>
```

whenever i change "intval" the graph doesnt display any data.....

anyone have any experience or ideas to help me out?

thank you.

Comment: `intval()` will return an integer value of whatever you pass as a parameter so that should not be a surprise that it returns a 1 when passed 1.024 etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently as stated in previous comments & answers, your script currently uses [`intval()`](https://www.php.net/intval) which, converts an given *number* and attempts to parse it to the nearest *whole number*, which effectively will strip out your decimal places.

Example from PHP [`intval()`](https://www.php.net/intval) docs:

```
echo intval(42);   // 42
echo intval(4.2);  // 4
```

There's a number of different methods in PHP to get decimal place values, but below I'll demonstrate PHP's `sprintf()`:

```
  //Input Value: 1.024                      
  sprintf( "%.2f", $row['test1'] ); //outputs 1.02
```

Secondly, you'll run into issues with the date string you'll be passing into the `$.plot()` function. Which you'll have to adjust for `$.plot` to understand your time value:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result ))  {
    $dataset1[] = array(
                    strtotime( $row['date'] ) * 1000,
                    sprintf( "%.2f", $row['test1'] )
                );
}
```

You'll need to add the `jquery.flot.time.js` script after declaring your `jquery.flot.js` too, in the image below I added `xaxis` to have a format of 'time' to decipher the time stamp.

```
  xaxis: { mode: "time",  timeformat: "%y/%m/%d" }
```

Providing you with the result:

[image]`$.plot()` Reference: [`$.plot data-format datetime`](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#data-format)

Comment: all seems to work but when i impliment your above code i get echo output for date as:

[0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1273096800000
            [1] => 1.024
        )

Comment: The long date is intended, as `$.plot` requires a javascript UNIX Timestamp (which are milliseconds) thus, lots of digits =)

Comment: Although be careful using `sprintf`; won't it return a string?  `flot` requires numeric values and a simple `floatval` would work.

Comment: That's very true! I've tested for both and they both yield the same result; possibly `flot` casts this in case?

Answer (score 0):

remove the intval() from your code except when you want the variable to be forced into an integer. Integers are whole numbers, like 1, 2, 3, 4.

If you send '1985-12-13' to intval, you'll get 1985, because it'll cut off the rest.

If you sent 1.2345 to intval, you'll get 1, again, cutting off the rest.

Perhaps you were copying code that used intval for a reason, but it your code it isn't needed. It isn't doing anything but messing up your results. Get rid of them.